# Icon themes not detected by KDE

Tags: icons, kde

I have been using KDE for a while. I installed a lot of themes on gnome but most of the themes don get detected here in kde ??? Why is that so ?? I like AwOken theme but it does not show up on KDE but I can see some themes like Faenza accessible on KDE. The most important theme that I wish now is AwOken. How do I get that back ???

Answer (score 0):

**By the AwOken**

https://launchpad.net/~alecive/+archive/antigone

The awoken-icon-theme_2.5~ppa1~raring1_all.deb has Installation_and_Instructions.pdf. It is telling:

> 3.2 KDE
>
> From 1.1 version of kAwOken iconset, there are two possibilities:
>
> DeviantArt download Download the iconset from the link provided in the
>   first page of this pdf. Extract the archive you downloaded, then
>   System Settings → Application Appearance → Icons and click the Install
>   Theme File button. Then, click the Open file dialog button on the
>   right of the location text entry, select the kAwOken.tar.gz file you
>   just extracted, and click the Ok button. To install also kAwOkenDark
>   and kAwOkenWhite iconset, you will have to iterate the same procedure.
>
> Using the ppa From the 1.1 Version, I mantain a ppa (Personal Package
>   Archive), to always get users syncronized with the latest updates of
>   the set. So it’s strongly recommended using this installation type.
>   The usage is very simple:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alecive/antigone && sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install kawoken-icon-theme
>
> This will install the iconset in /usr/share/icons folder, so the
>   directory is different from the usual installation through DeviantArt.
>
> Now you can start customizing your iconset the way you want. You’d
>   find very useful the instructions shown below.

If the kAwOken iconset is not working then inform the developer/packager.

Quote from https://launchpad.net/~alecive/+archive/antigone :

> For questions and bugs with software in this PPA please contact
>   alecive.